# Can a system have negative entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

We know that the entropy is zero for reversible processes and always positive for irreversible processes. Can there exist a system which may have negative entropy?

Comment: I think you are talking about entropy **change** in a process, correct?

Comment: Why entropy of the whole system is zero or greater than zero but not negative?

Comment: What do you define as the"whole system?"

Comment: Means our object of interest

Comment: like the entropy of universe is always increasing but why ?

Comment: Is our object of interest capable of exchanging heat or work with its surroundings?

Comment: No.. its a closed system

Comment: I think we have a terminology issue here. When a physicist talks about a closed system, what he means is one in which there is no exchange of mass, heat, or work with the surroundings; this is what we engineers call an **isolated** system. In engineering (and most thermo books), a closed system is one in which there is no exchange of mass with the surroundings; exchange of heat and work are allowed. See the following link: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=closed+system+thermodynamics&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8  Care to comment?

Comment: Sir..can you explain it by considering both types of system as you described above?

Comment: In a closed system (i.e., no mass exchange with surroundings, but heat and work exchange allowed), the entropy will decrease if you compress an ideal gas isothermally.  But, if the system is isolated (i.e., no mass, heat, or work exchange with the surroundings), entropy can only be generated within the system, but not transferred to its surroundings.  So its entropy can only increase or remain constant.

Answer (score 6):

The entropy $S$ of a system is related to the number of possible microstates $\Omega$ that a system can adopt in the following way:

$$S = k_B \log \Omega$$

Note that $\Omega$ must always be an integer, and it must always be at least 1; hence, $S$ is always greater than or equal to zero.

In the zero-entropy case, the object is a perfect crystal at zero temperature, which has only one possible microstate. (Thus, the above definition is made possible by the Third Law of Thermodynamics.) Any other situation has more than one possible microstate, so the entropy must be greater than zero.

Comment: Can we corelate the entropy with randomness

Comment: Assuming a uniform probability distribution of the system being in any one microstate, then yes, the approximate "randomness" of a system is related to its total number of microstates, and thus to the entropy.

Comment: We know what happened at absolute zero but what will happen below 0K

Comment: It depends on your definition of temperature. If you relate it to average particle kinetic energy, then it is impossible, as kinetic energy is always positive. If you define temperature as 1/(the amount of entropy added to the system when a given amount of energy is added), then negative temperatures are possible in systems that become more orderly (i.e. have fewer microstates) when energy is added. Most practical examples of such systems are generally quite hot, though, so this notion of temperature is somewhat non-intuitive.

Comment: Can you describe the concept of negative temperature more clearly

Comment: If an upper limit exists on the amount of energy a particle can have, then adding energy to a system pas a certain point serves to pack more and more particles into (for bosons) the highest energy state, or (in the case of fermions) the highest available energy state. A bunch of indistinguishable degenerate particles (in the case of bosons; in the case of fermions, a bunch of indistinguishable particles who are essentially locked in one energy state) is much less random than a bunch of particles  which have many possible energy states. Thus, higher-energy states have less entropy.

Comment: Yaah...now it is more clear

Answer (score 5):

I think what you mean is that the entropy doesn't change for reversible processes, but increases for irreversible processes. In this sense your question would be if the entropy of a system can decrease. Yes, absolutely! The entropy can decrease for a system that is not closed. For example, Earth receives the solar energy prom the Sun and dissipates it into space as heat. The entropy of the whole (closed) system (Sun, Earth, and space) always increases. However, the entropy on Earth alone can indeed decrease. Entropy is often referred to as a measure of chaos, so order would be the opposite of entropy. In this sense biological life and evolution represent a highly organized matter and therefore a low entropy. Such a reduction of the entropy as the emergence of life and its evolution on Earth was possible exactly because Earth alone is not a closed system, but a conduit of a tremendous entropy increase of the solar energy dissipating as heat. Without this constant entropy increase, life on Earth would be impossible. It is exactly the entropy increase in the entire system that allowed the entropy in the part of the system to decrease thus producing life, evolution, and ultimately intelligence.

Comment: Even in a closed system, the entropy can decrease.  Just remove heat from a body, for example.

Comment: @Chester Miller: Could you please provide a link or reference to the idea that the entropy of a closed system can decrease?

Comment: Well, every thermodynamics text book has the equation $dS=dq_{rev}/T$.  What would you conclude if I told you that $dq_{rev}$ is negative for a particular process (such as isothermal compression of an ideal gas or cooling a solid)?

Comment: @Chester Miller: Your examples are not closed systems and they do not answer my question. I am not asking for ideas or conclusions. I am asking if you can provide a reference specifically stating that "the entropy of a closed system can decrease". The reason I am asking is that such a system would violate the law of the entropy increasing in a closed system and I haven't heard of any violations of this law. So if you have any actual reference (other than your own deductions), I'd be interested to learn.

Comment: I think we have a terminology issue here. When a physicist talks about a closed system, what he means is one in which there is no exchange of mass, heat, or work with the surroundings; this is what we engineers call an *isolated* system. In engineering (and most thermo books), a closed system is one in which there is no exchange of mass with the surroundings; exchange of heat and work are allowed.  See the following link:  https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=closed+system+thermodynamics&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Mass / energy equivalence might account for the difference between the physicists' definition and the engineers', as it would rarely affect current engineering work.